# Live agent hand-off using Azure chat bot

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service, handoff

I am working on a requirement where I need to transfer the chat to a live agent in case QnA has no solution to the user's query. I know that this is possible using Power virtual agents in Azure but I need to know if this can be achieved without using PVA. I have gone through multiple samples and all samples are using channel specific code ex: Microsoft Teams. Below is one of the sample called hand off library but I believe this is only one half of the code.

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/experimental/handoff-library/csharp_dotnetcore/samples

Can anyone please guide me on how to achieve this?

Comment: You can use the following sample for live agent handover using Azure Bot framework. You can try understanding the following https://github.com/cdonke/intermediator-bot-sample.

Comment: You can go through the following answer for more details : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66389478/microsoft-bot-framework-handover-solution-to-support-agents-in-ms-teams/66418681#66418681

Comment: Unfortunately, as written, this is off-topic: it's a very broad question seeking general guidance/documentation. Please ask specific questions (along with work you've done and issues you're running into).