# Issue in sending QnA Bot message to Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service, botframework

I have a scenario to have Q&A bot were user will get interact suppose if user ask any specific question and answer for that question is not available in Q&A maker than that question must be forwarded to Microsoft Teams and intermediate person will reply for the same which in return must be updated in Q&A Maker as well as replied to the user. It must be from Website <-> Bot <-> Microsoft Teams

So I have created a new Q&A maker and Q&A Bot which is working perfectly fine as well as we have the code for Updating Q&A answers in Q&A Maker. Remaining stuff is to send that question to Microsoft Teams.
I have also created a teams channel and Microsoft Teams Bot using App Studio. I am using the C# language.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off topic

Comment: I think you are looking for handoff kind of scenario and You can do it this approach using proactive messaging. You can check this as a reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66389478/microsoft-bot-framework-handover-solution-to-support-agents-in-ms-teams/66418681#66418681