# Skip bot when messaging in Azure bot service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I have implemented a customer care chat service using C# bot framework sdk and azure bot service where azure bot work as a middleman. when customer send a message, bot pick the message and send to a suitable agent. However after the initial conversation, I want to skip the bot and do the conversation between the customer and agent. Is there anyway to implement this?

Comment: Here bot is always a middleware and already the communication started inside the respective channel. If you want to switch the conversation between customer and agent then you need to implement a handover kind of functionality. I think there the information is handled through the separately created conversation tunnel. The 2nd approach you can verify - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66389478/microsoft-bot-framework-handover-solution-to-support-agents-in-ms-teams/66418681#66418681

Comment: So far I have seen your question, based on your SDK and current environment you can use omnichannel to transfer your conversation from bot to human agent. You can get details guideline [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-service/configure-bot#introduction). Make sure you have gone through the [prerequisites part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-service/configure-bot#prerequisites) accordingly. If you need sample code please check [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-service/bot-escalate-end-conversation#sample-code)

Comment: Additionally you can have a look directly [here in the sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/experimental/handoff-library/csharp_dotnetcore/samples/DynamicsOmnichannelBot/Bots/DynamicsOmnichannelAgentBot.cs#L35) how it works.